# Return an object from an array list in a thread safe way?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, concurrency, thread-safety

I have a class in which I am populating a map `liveSocketsByDatacenter` from a single background thread every 30 seconds inside `updateLiveSockets()` method and then I have a method `getNextSocket()` which will be called by multiple reader threads to get a live socket available which uses the same map to get this information.

```
public class SocketManager {
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  private final AtomicReference<Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
      new AtomicReference<>(Collections.unmodifiableMap(new HashMap<>()));
  private final ZContext ctx = new ZContext();

  // Lazy Loaded Singleton Pattern
  private static class Holder {
    private static final SocketManager instance = new SocketManager();
  }

  public static SocketManager getInstance() {
    return Holder.instance;
  }

  private SocketManager() {
    connectToZMQSockets();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        updateLiveSockets();
      }
    }, 30, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  // during startup, making a connection and populate once
  private void connectToZMQSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;
    // The map in which I put all the live sockets
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> updatedLiveSocketsByDatacenter = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> addedColoSockets = connect(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), ZMQ.PUSH);
      updatedLiveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(),
          Collections.unmodifiableList(addedColoSockets));
    }
    // Update the map content
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.set(Collections.unmodifiableMap(updatedLiveSocketsByDatacenter));
  }

  private List<SocketHolder> connect(Datacenters colo, List<String> addresses, int socketType) {
    List<SocketHolder> socketList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String address : addresses) {
      try {
        Socket client = ctx.createSocket(socketType);
        // Set random identity to make tracing easier
        String identity = String.format("%04X-%04X", random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
        client.setIdentity(identity.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));
        client.setTCPKeepAlive(1);
        client.setSendTimeOut(7);
        client.setLinger(0);
        client.connect(address);

        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(client, ctx, address, true);
        socketList.add(zmq);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        // log error
      }
    }
    return socketList;
  }

  // this method will be called by multiple threads to get the next live socket
  // is there any concurrency or thread safety issue or race condition here?
  public Optional<SocketHolder> getNextSocket() {
    // For the sake of consistency make sure to use the same map instance
    // in the whole implementation of my method by getting my entries
    // from the local variable instead of the member variable
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
        this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.get();
    Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = Optional.absent();
    List<Datacenters> dcs = Datacenters.getOrderedDatacenters();
    for (Datacenters dc : dcs) {
      liveSocket = getLiveSocket(liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(dc));
      if (liveSocket.isPresent()) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return liveSocket;
  }

  // is there any concurrency or thread safety issue or race condition here?
  private Optional<SocketHolder> getLiveSocketX(final List<SocketHolder> endpoints) {
    if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(endpoints)) {
      // The list of live sockets
      List<SocketHolder> liveOnly = new ArrayList<>(endpoints.size());
      for (SocketHolder obj : endpoints) {
        if (obj.isLive()) {
          liveOnly.add(obj);
        }
      }
      if (!liveOnly.isEmpty()) {
        // The list is not empty so we shuffle it an return the first element
        Collections.shuffle(liveOnly);
        return Optional.of(liveOnly.get(0));
      }
    }
    return Optional.absent();
  }

  // Added the modifier synchronized to prevent concurrent modification
  // it is needed because to build the new map we first need to get the
  // old one so both must be done atomically to prevent concistency issues
  private synchronized void updateLiveSockets() {
    Map<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> socketsByDatacenter = Utils.SERVERS;

    // Initialize my new map with the current map content
    Map<Datacenters, List<SocketHolder>> liveSocketsByDatacenter =
        new HashMap<>(this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.get());

    for (Entry<Datacenters, ImmutableList<String>> entry : socketsByDatacenter.entrySet()) {
      List<SocketHolder> liveSockets = liveSocketsByDatacenter.get(entry.getKey());
      List<SocketHolder> liveUpdatedSockets = new ArrayList<>();
      for (SocketHolder liveSocket : liveSockets) { // LINE A
        Socket socket = liveSocket.getSocket();
        String endpoint = liveSocket.getEndpoint();
        Map<byte[], byte[]> holder = populateMap();
        Message message = new Message(holder, Partition.COMMAND);

        boolean status = SendToSocket.getInstance().execute(message.getAdd(), holder, socket);
        boolean isLive = (status) ? true : false;
        // is there any problem the way I am using `SocketHolder` class?
        SocketHolder zmq = new SocketHolder(socket, liveSocket.getContext(), endpoint, isLive);
        liveUpdatedSockets.add(zmq);
      }
      liveSocketsByDatacenter.put(entry.getKey(),
          Collections.unmodifiableList(liveUpdatedSockets));
    }
    this.liveSocketsByDatacenter.set(Collections.unmodifiableMap(liveSocketsByDatacenter));
  }
}
```

As you can see in my class:

- From a single background thread which runs every 30 seconds, I populate `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map with all the live sockets in `updateLiveSockets()` method.
- And then from multiple threads, I call the `getNextSocket()` method to give me a live socket available which uses a `liveSocketsByDatacenter` map to get the required information.

I have my code working fine without any issues and wanted to see if there is any better or more efficient way to write this. I also wanted to get an opinion on thread safety issues or any race conditions if any are there, but so far I haven't seen any but I could be wrong.

I am mostly worried about `updateLiveSockets()` method and `getLiveSocketX()` method. I am iterating `liveSockets` which is a `List` of `SocketHolder` at LINE A and then making a new `SocketHolder` object and adding to another new list. Is this ok here?

**Note:** `SocketHolder` is an immutable class.

Comment: Well, code C. There's no point in shuffling N elements to pick 1 at random.

Comment: The thread safety of the code depends on what else you're doing to the `endpoints` list elsewhere in the code. If another thread is able to modify it while you're executing this method, it's not thread safe.

Comment: I think I wrote my question too fast. `endpoints` list can contains sockets which are not live so in my `Code B` I am iterating the original list and making a new list with all live socket in it and then calling shufle and getting first index out of it. In my `Code C`, I am getting random index directly on the list. So it looks I need to add that code back which makes a new list of live sockets and then using ThreadLocalRandom to get the random index right?

Comment: I updated my `Code C` again. Now `Code B` and `Code C` should be doing exact same thing I believe.

Comment: Your edit adds too much code; it is now very unclear what you are asking. Please cut it down to a [mcve]. (It's impossible to say if you invoke `getLiveSocketX` in a thread-safe way - it is as important how you invoke it as what is in it - if you don't actually invoke `getLiveSocketX` in the code).

Answer (score 2):

Neither of codes B or C is thread-safe.

**Code B**

When you are iterating on the `enpoints` list to copy it, nothing prevents another thread to modify, *i.e.* elements to be added and/or removed.

**Code C**

Assuming `endpoints` is not null, you are doing three calls to the list object: `isEmpty`, `size`, and `get`. There are several problems from a concurrency perspective:

1. Based on the type `List<SocketHolder>` of the argument, there is no guarantee that these methods enforce internal changes to the list to be propagated to other threads (memory visibility), let apart race conditions (if the list is modified while while your thread execute one of this function).
2. Let's suppose that the list `endpoints` provide the guarantee described just before - e.g. it has been wrapped with `Collections.synchronizedList()`. In this case, thread safety is still missing because between each of the calls to `isEmpty`, `size`, and `get`, the list can be modified while your thread executes the `getLiveSocketX` method. This could make your code use an outdated state of the list. For instance, your could use a size returned by `endpoints.size()` which is no longer valid because an element has been added to or removed from the list.

**Edit - after code update**

In the code you provided, it seems at first sight that:

1. You are indeed not co-modifying the `endpoints` list we were discussing about before in the method `getLiveSocketX`, because the method `updateLiveSockets` creates a new list `liveUpdatedSockets` which you populate from the existing `liveSockets`.
2. You use an `AtomicReference` to keep a map of `Datacenters` to the lists of sockets of interest. The consequences of this `AtomicReference` is to force memory visibility from this map down to all the lists and their elements. This means that, *by side-effect*, you are protected from memory inconsistencies between your "producer" and "consumer" threads (executing `updateLiveSockets` and `getLiveSocket` respectively). You are still exposed to race conditions, though - let's imagine `updateLiveSockets` and `getLiveSocket` running at the same time. Consider a socket `S` which status just switches from alive to closed. `updateLiveSockets` will see the status of a socket `S` as non-alive and create a new `SocketHolder` accordingly. However, `getLiveSocket` which is running at the exact same time will see an outdated state of `S` - since it will still use the list of sockets which `updateLiveSockets` is re-creating.
3. The `synchronized` keyword used on the method `updateLiveSockets` does not provide you any guarantee here, because no other part of the code is also `synchronized`.

To summarize, I would say:

1. The code of `getLiveSocketX` as it is written is **not** *inherently* thread-safe;
2. However, the way you copy the lists prevents concurrent modifications; and you are benefiting from a **side-effect** of the `AtomicReference` to have the minimal guarantee on memory visibility one would expect to get consistent list of sockets in `getNextSocket` after those have been generated from another thread;
3. You are still exposed to race conditions as described in (2), but this may be fine depending on the specifications you wish to confer to the `getLiveSocket` and `getNextSocket` methods - you may accept one socket returned by the `getLiveSocket` to be unavailable and have a retry mechanism.

All of that being said, I would thoroughly review and refactor the code to exhibit a more readable and explicit thread-safe consumer/producer pattern. Extra care should be taken with the use of the `AtomicReference` and the single `synchronized`, which seem to me being improperly used - although *in fine* the `AtomicReference` does help you as discussed before.

Comment: hmmm I didn't follow what is the race condition we are hitting here? And what is the best way you think to solve this producer consumer problem?

Comment: @user1950349: Will try to provide you with some code tonight (10-12 hours from now)

Comment: @user1950349: So I had a look at your code and tried to see what could be changed. I may be wrong here, but since `updateLiveSockets` seems to only update the status of the socket holders, why do you create new `SocketHolder` objects and their containers ? Is it because you want to have an immutable `SocketHolder` object? In this particular case, it could make sense to allow the `SocketHolder`'s status to be mutated (obviously in a thread-safe way). Is there any reason against it?

Comment: yeah I just did because just to have an immutable `SocketHolder` object. Is there anything wrong I did?

Comment: Nothing wrong, it is generally a good practice to design your classes to be immutable. In the present case, I do not know enough about the rest of your codebase (e.g. which code is using `SocketHolder` objects, how they are used, will there be potential flaws if you can mutate the status, etc.), but it seems that you could save you from copying the maps and the lists of sockets in `SocketManager` if you allow the status of a `SocketHolder` to be updated - for instance using a `volatile boolean status`.

Comment: `SocketHolder` class is being used only from this `SocketManager` class only,  that's all and nobody else is using this class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157955/discussion-between-alexandre-dupriez-and-user1950349).